# Rest API to get Power BI Embed Token Returns "Bad Request"

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I am currently trying to work through a bit of code I obtained from GuyInACube.  However, I am having a hard time getting it to actually work.  Could be me since I am rather new to using embed tokens.

[Video Link if Interested](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNF-_l2f7w0)

Error Message:

```
Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperations.<GenerateTokenInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.<GenerateTokenInGroupAsync>d__87.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GenerateTokenInGroup(IReportsOperations operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId, GenerateTokenRequest requestParameters)
   at EmbedAPISample.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - irth Solutions\Documents\Projects\Power BI\Embed-API-Sample-master\Embed-API-Sample-master\EmbedAPISample\Program.cs:line 56
```

I have modified their code to add my ID's and client secrets.  I also created a new Azure AD Appliction Registration and granted all delegation api access for Power BI Service.

I then added the Azure AD Application from above to my Power BI Workspace that contains my dataset and report as an admin.

However, I am still getting a "BadRequest" when I try to run the code.  Are there any other steps that I am Missing?

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api;
using Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.Models;
using Microsoft.Rest;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmbedAPISample
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool useEmbedToken = true;
        private static bool useRLS = false;

        private static string authorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/";
        private static string resourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
        private static string apiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/";

        private static string tenantId = "TENANT";
        private static Guid groupId = Guid.Parse("GROUPID");



        private static Guid reportId = Guid.Parse("REPORTID");
        private static Guid datasetId = Guid.Parse("DATASETID");

        // **** Update the Client ID and Secret within Secrets.cs ****

        private static ClientCredential credential = null;
        private static AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
        private static TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                // Create a user password cradentials.
                credential = new ClientCredential(Secrets.ClientID, Secrets.ClientSecret);

                // Authenticate using created credentials
                Authorize().Wait();

                using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), tokenCredentials))
                {

                    #region Embed Token
                    EmbedToken embedToken = null;


                    if (useEmbedToken && !useRLS)
                    {
                        // **** Without RLS ****
                        embedToken = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(groupId, reportId, 
                            new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "View", datasetId: datasetId.ToString()));
                    }
                    else if(useEmbedToken && useRLS)
                    {
                        // **** With RLS ****

                        // Documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security
                        // Example: 
                        //
                        // Define Embed Token request:
                        //var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest("View", null, 
                        //    identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity> { new EffectiveIdentity(username: "username", 
                        //        roles: new List<string> { "roleA", "roleB" }, 
                        //        datasets: new List<string> { "datasetId" }) });
                        // 
                        // Generate Embed Token:
                        //var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync("groupId", "reportId", 
                        //    generateTokenRequestParameters);

                        var rls = new EffectiveIdentity(username: "<ENTER USERNAME>", new List<string> { datasetId.ToString() });

                        var rolesList = new List<string>();
                        rolesList.Add("<ENTER ROLE>");
                        rls.Roles = rolesList;

                        embedToken = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(groupId, reportId, 
                            new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "View", datasetId: datasetId.ToString(), rls));
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Output Embed Token

                    if (useEmbedToken)
                    {
                        // Get a single report used for embedding
                        Report report = client.Reports.GetReportInGroup(groupId, reportId);

                        Console.WriteLine("\r*** EMBED TOKEN ***\r");

                        Console.Write("Report Id: ");

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                        Console.WriteLine(reportId);
                        Console.ResetColor();

                        Console.Write("Report Embed Url: ");

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                        Console.WriteLine(report.EmbedUrl);
                        Console.ResetColor();

                        Console.WriteLine("Embed Token Expiration: ");

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                        Console.WriteLine(embedToken.Expiration.ToString());
                        Console.ResetColor();


                        Console.WriteLine("Report Embed Token: ");
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                        Console.WriteLine(embedToken.Token);
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Output Datasets
                    Console.WriteLine("\r*** DATASETS ***\r");

                    try
                    {
                        // List of Datasets
                        // This method calls for items in a Group/App Workspace. To get a list of items within your "My Workspace"
                        // call GetDatasets()
                        var datasetList = client.Datasets.GetDatasetsInGroup(groupId);

                        foreach (Dataset ds in datasetList.Value)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ds.Id + " | " + ds.Name);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Error fetching datasets: " + ex.Message);
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Output Reports
                    Console.WriteLine("\r*** REPORTS ***\r");

                    try
                    {
                        // List of reports
                        // This method calls for items in a Group/App Workspace. To get a list of items within your "My Workspace"
                        // call GetReports()
                        var reportList = client.Reports.GetReportsInGroup(groupId);

                        foreach (Report rpt in reportList.Value)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(rpt.Id + " | " + rpt.Name + " | DatasetID = " + rpt.DatasetId);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Error fetching reports: " + ex.Message);
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Output Dashboards
                    Console.WriteLine("\r*** DASHBOARDS ***\r");

                    try
                    {
                        // List of reports
                        // This method calls for items in a Group/App Workspace. To get a list of items within your "My Workspace"
                        // call GetReports()
                        var dashboards = client.Dashboards.GetDashboardsInGroup(groupId);

                        foreach (Dashboard db in dashboards.Value)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(db.Id + " | " + db.DisplayName);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Error fetching dashboards: " + ex.Message);
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                    #endregion

                    #region Output Gateways
                    Console.WriteLine("\r*** Gateways ***\r");

                    try
                    {
                        var gateways = client.Gateways.GetGateways();

                        Console.WriteLine(gateways.Value[0].Name);

                        //foreach (Gateway g in gateways)
                        //{
                        //    Console.WriteLine(g.Name + " | " + g.GatewayStatus);
                        //}
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Error fetching gateways: " + ex.Message);
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                    #endregion
                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

        }

        private static Task Authorize()
        {
            return Task.Run(async () => {
                authenticationResult = null;
                tokenCredentials = null;

                // TENANT ID is required when using a Service Principal
                var tenantSpecificURL = authorityUrl.Replace("organizations", tenantId);

                var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(tenantSpecificURL);

                authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, credential);

                if (authenticationResult != null)
                {
                    tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
                }
            });
        }






    }
}
```

Edit:

Below are the permissions I've setup and where I retrieved the id's I've used.  I am not seeing what I am missing on these.

I've created a Power BI Embed Test Application Registration with the below permissions:

[image]

I then added that Power BI Embed Test to my workspace as an admin:

[image]

I then grabbed the tenant and client ids from here:

[image]

Once I did that I grabbed the Dataset ID from here (Marked in red)
[image]

And finally the report id from here (marked in red)

[image]

Stepping through the code I found this error.  Currently researching how to fix:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Creating embed token for accessing dataset   requires effective identity to be provided"}}
```

Comment: Able to generate the embed token using the same repository and not facing any such error. Please verify, If you have all the required permission and ensure the values entered for tenantId, reportId, groupId and datasetId are correct.

 Please refer to [SO Ticket #54404188](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404188/power-bi-send-invalid-status-code-bad-request-for-a-cached-datasetid/54416182#54416182) this might be a reason for the bad request.

Comment: hi @Madhav I appreciate your response.  I've added the steps I've taken so far to resolve this as well.  Including the permissions I've granted.  If you could let me know what I may be missing it would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was able to generate the embed token after I removed the try/catch to find the real error that Madhav alluded to.  Which was effective identity.

changed the rls from false to true, ran it, provided my username and it worked.