# Create an Power BI embed token for an on prem SSAS

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerbi-embedded

I am working to create an embed token for an on prem ssas connection.  With the ultimate goal of passing the security through so that I can use the role security in ssas in power bi.

however, my first step is generating the initial embed token.  As I am new to embed this is turning into an ordeal.

I was able to successfully create an embed token using the below code for a regular Power BI dataset with RLS with the below code.

This is related to a [similar post i made yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956797/rest-api-to-get-power-bi-embed-token-returns-bad-request?noredirect=1#comment135671825_76956797).  However, I got that to work now I'm trying to do SSAS On Prem.  My setup for security is the same as the post above.  Except I added the Azure AD Application Registration to the workspace and to the gateway I am using.

```
 private static bool useEmbedToken = true;
 private static bool useRLS = true;

 private static string authorityUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/";
 private static string resourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
 private static string apiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/";

 private static string tenantId = "TENANT";  //Working
 private static Guid groupId = Guid.Parse("GROUP");

 private static Guid reportId = Guid.Parse("REPORT");//
 private static Guid datasetId = Guid.Parse("DATASET"); //


 // **** Update the Client ID and Secret within Secrets.cs ****

 private static ClientCredential credential = null;
 private static AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
 private static TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = null;

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {

     //try
     {
         // Create a user password cradentials.
         credential = new ClientCredential(Secrets.ClientID, Secrets.ClientSecret);

         // Authenticate using created credentials
         Authorize().Wait();

         using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), tokenCredentials))
         {

             #region Embed Token
             EmbedToken embedToken = null;


             if (useEmbedToken && !useRLS)
             {
                

             }
             else if (useEmbedToken && useRLS)
             {
                 // **** With RLS ****

                 

                 var rls = new EffectiveIdentity(username: "USER@COMPANY.com", new List<string> { datasetId.ToString() });

                 var rolesList = new List<string>();
                 rolesList.Add("Role");
                 rls.Roles = rolesList;

                 embedToken = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(groupId, reportId,
                     new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "View", datasetId: datasetId.ToString(), rls));

                 //var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequestV2(
                 //    datasets:  datasetId.ToString(),
                 //    reports: reportId,
                 //    targetWorkspaces: groupId,
                 //    allowEdit: true,
                 //    accessLevel: "view";
             }
```

However, when I attempt to do this with SSAS On Prem I get the message "Forbidden"

```
Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
  Source=Microsoft.PowerBI.Api
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperations.<GenerateTokenInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.<GenerateTokenInGroupAsync>d__95.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.ReportsOperationsExtensions.GenerateTokenInGroup(IReportsOperations operations, Guid groupId, Guid reportId, GenerateTokenRequest requestParameters)
   at EmbedAPISample.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\Projects\Power BI\Embed-API-Sample-master\Embed-API-Sample-master\EmbedAPISample\Program.cs:line 111
```

I have setup a Azure AD Application Registration, and I have granted it all of the delegated responsibilities.

I then added that Principal Name to the workspace as well as my gateway

I have also mapped the effective username so it would go "user@Company.com" to "User@Staging.com" as the roles in SSAS use staging as their domain.

This same code works for a non SSAS dataset in the same workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this after I found this [troubleshooting link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-troubleshoot) provided by another user.

Once I finally got that added to my code it parsed out the real error message which was:

```
Request: {
 "accessLevel": "View",
  "datasetId": "DATASET",
  "identities": [
    {
      "username": "USER@COMPANY.com",
      "datasets": [
        "DATASET"
      ],
      "roles": [
        "Role"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
Status: Forbidden (403)
 Response: {"error":{"code":"InvalidRequest","message":"Creating embed token for accessing dataset DATASET requires gateway admin or datasource override effective identity access right"}}
RequestId: REQUESTID
```

I then found an article stating to add a user to the gateway as an admin you need to go to the [Power Platform admin center](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/requires-gateway-admin/m-p/2493343) and add the service principal (or it's user group) there.  Once I did that everything worked